# Excel Export in Nova using Existing Template

Tags: laravel-nova

I want to Export data of a Nova resource in an existing Excel File.

Have created an Action file to export the data of a Nova resource with Heading and Mapping. But Want to use an existing Excel file template and populate it with data.

```
    public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [
        (new ExportListing())->withFilename('listings-' . time() . '.xlsx')
        ->only('idx', 'TitleUnlimited', 'TitleLanguage', 'TitleClass', 'TitleAlternate1', 'TitleAlternateLanguage1', 'TitleAlternateClass1', 'TitleAlternate2',
            'TitleAlternateLanguage2', 'TitleAlternateClass2')
    ];

}
```